# SwiftUI Health kit blood Presure query

Tags: swift, swiftui, healthkit

i am trying to make an app to read the.blood presure from health kit.

on the line - `self.dataX.bloodPresureDetails.append(sysPresData)` (third line from the bottom in the first block)
im getting this error

> Thread 2: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type UserHealthDetails
> found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for UserHealthDetails may be
> missing as an ancestor of this view.

HalthStore file

```
class HealthStore {
@EnvironmentObject var dataX: UserHealthDetails
var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
var sampleQuery: HKSampleQuery?

init() {
    if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    }
}

func requestAutherisation(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    let presSystolic = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureSystolic)!
    let presDiastolic = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressureDiastolic)!
    let heartRate = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!

    guard let healthStore = self.healthStore else { return completion(false) }
 
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [presSystolic, presDiastolic, heartRate]) { (sucsess, error) in
        completion(sucsess)
    }
}


 func readSampleByBloodPressure(){
     
            guard let bloodtype = HKQuantityType.correlationType(forIdentifier: HKCorrelationTypeIdentifier.bloodPressure),
           let systolicType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic),
           let diastolicType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic) else {

               return
       }

      let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!
     let endDate = Date()
     let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: true)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)
      sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: bloodtype, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
         { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

            if let dataList = results as? [HKCorrelation] {

             for data in dataList
             {
                 if let data1 = data.objects(for: systolicType).first as? HKQuantitySample,
                     let data2 = data.objects(for: diastolicType).first as? HKQuantitySample {

                     let sysPvalue = data1.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.millimeterOfMercury())
                     let diaPvalue = data2.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.millimeterOfMercury())

                    let sysPresData = UserHealthDetails.BloodPresure(diaPres: diaPvalue, sysPres: sysPvalue, date: startDate)
                    
                    self.dataX.bloodPresureDetails.append(sysPresData)
                 }
             }

     }

 }
 
 
if let healthStore = healthStore,
let sampleQuery = self.sampleQuery { healthStore.execute(sampleQuery) }


 }
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {

private var healthStore: HealthStore?
@EnvironmentObject var dataX: UserHealthDetails

init () {
    healthStore = HealthStore()
}

static let dateFormat: DateFormatter = {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.dateStyle = .long
       return formatter
   }()

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        List{
            ForEach(dataX.bloodPresureDetails, id: \.self) { data in
                Text("\(data.diaPres)")
                
            }
        }
       
    }
   
    
    
        .onAppear {
            if let healthStore = self.healthStore {
                healthStore.requestAutherisation { sucsess in
                    if sucsess {
                        healthStore.readSampleByBloodPressure()
                        print("readSampleByBloodPressure")
                        }
                    
                }
            }
    }
    
}
```

Class

```
class UserHealthDetails: ObservableObject {

@Published var bloodPresureDetails: [BloodPresure] = []


struct BloodPresure: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let diaPres: Double
    let sysPres: Double
    let date: Date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@EnvironmentObject` variables are picked up from the environment, which means that a superview needs to provide them using the `.environmentObject(_:)` function on any `View` type. You don't appear to be doing that, so your `ContentView` is crashing when it tries to access the `@EnvironmentObject` var you have defined.

[Here's a link on how you should fix this problem](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)

---

As a side note, your `HealthStore` class has this line:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var dataX: UserHealthDetails
```

which you don't seem to be using (and I don't think you're supposed to use `@EnvironmentObject` outside of `Views`), so you might want to remove that.